# Quadratic and Cubic Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I came across the following Differential Equation
$$y'(x) = a \cdot y(x) + b \cdot y(x)^2 + c \cdot y(x)^3$$ Where $a,b,c$ are numerical coefficients.

I can solve it numerically, but I would like to solve it analytically. Is there some trick or substitution that might make it easier to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Solve $cy^2 + by + a = 0$. Let the roots be $y_0, y_1$. Now decompose $\dfrac{y'}{y(y-y_0)(y-y_1)}$ into $A\dfrac{y'}{y} + B\dfrac{y'}{y - y_0} + C\dfrac{y'}{y - y_1}$. Each of them is easily integratabtle. Can you continue?

Comment: I am sorry, but can you explain it again from the beginning, I don’t understand how you got there and how to continue forward. Thank you

Comment: Using the roots $0,y_0,y_1$ of the cubic on the right side, you can write $y'=ay(y-y_0)(y-y_1)$. Now apply the standard package of separation of variables and partial fraction decomposition.